# How should we use negative form in optative sentence? Should it be 'may he not get sick' or 'may not he get sick'?

Tags: sentence-construction

How should we use negative form in optative sentence? Should it be 'may he not get sick' or 'may not he get sick' ?

Answer (score 12):

Optative *may* is obsolescent in present-day English, perhaps even wholly obsolete outside of literary contexts. Most people would say or write something like:

> Let's hope he doesn't get sick.

But if some examiner with a taste for 19th-century diction insists on your building this with *may*, your first option is correct:

> May he not get sick.

*May not he get sick* is a question asking whether it is not possible that he will get sick.